# Best way to update an entire document in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, nosql

I would like to replace an xml document in a database without any metadata (e.g. permissions, properties or collections). Managed documents (dls) is not an option.

Using `xdmp:document-insert()` does not retain permissions, collections etc.

Using `xdmp:node-replace()` works well with parts of the document but requires knowing the root node in advance.

Is there a recommended way to update an entire document in MarkLogic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't really need to know the root element itself. If you know the document URI, you can do something like:

```
xdmp:node-replace(fn:doc($uri)/*, $new-xml)
```

If you have any node of the document, you can also do:

```
xdmp:node-replace($node/fn:root(), $new-xml)
```

But just using `xdmp:document-insert()` isn't that much more difficult either:

```
xdmp:document-insert($uri, $new-xml, xdmp:document-get-permissions($uri), xdmp:document-get-collections($uri), xdmp:document-get-quality($uri))
```

Note: document-properties are preserved at document-insert. See also: http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert

Additionally, there is not much performance difference between these methods. The biggest difference in that respect is that `xdmp:node-replace()` requires a node from the original document, meaning it has to be retrieved from the database first. If the replacement does not depend on the original document, then `xdmp:document-insert()` would be fastest.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @grtjn.   Note that *why* using xdmp:node-replace is no more efficient then xdmp:document-insert is that all document updates update the entire document. It is a common understandable misconception that xdmp:node-replace would operate similar to say an RDBMS field update -- only 'touching' the affected field.  In the RDBMS case that is often a mistaken misconception as well.

Similar to not needing to read the old document body, if you know what the permissions, collections, and quality should be you can supply those (or defaults) rather than querying them with xdmp:document-get-permissions() etc.  It may not make a measurable difference, but as with xdmp:node-replace() if you don't need to query a value its simpler not to -- and removes unneeded dependencies and error opportunities (such as what if the document doesn't exist?)